# Show that two curves with same curvature and torsions $\tau_\alpha=\pm\tau_\beta$ are congruent.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Definition: Two curves $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ are congruent if there exists an isometry $m\in Iso(3,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\beta=m(\alpha(s))$.

$\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ are two curves with
$$\begin{cases}
\kappa_\alpha(s)=\kappa_\beta(s)\\
\tau_\alpha(s)=\pm\tau_\beta(s)
\end{cases}$$
I have to show that both are congruent.

The case where
$$\begin{cases}
\kappa_\alpha(s)=\kappa_\beta(s)\\
\tau_\alpha(s)=\tau_\beta(s)
\end{cases}$$
is trivial due to Fundamental Theorem of Existence and Uniqueness of Curves in the space.

The case left is
$$\begin{cases}
\kappa_\alpha(s)=\kappa_\beta(s)\\
\tau_\alpha(s)=-\tau_\beta(s)
\end{cases}.$$

Both curves are parametrized with arc-length, so we can use Frenet frame, what I've got so far is:

$$T_\alpha'=\kappa_\alpha N_\alpha=\kappa_\beta N_\alpha$$
so $$\langle T_\alpha',N_\alpha\rangle=\kappa_\alpha,$$
then $$T_\beta'=\langle T_\alpha',N_\alpha\rangle N_\beta.$$
But that is pretty obvious since $T_\alpha'\parallel N_\alpha$ when it is arc-length parametrized.

From definition of torsion we also have $$\langle B_\alpha',N_\alpha\rangle=\pm-\langle B_\beta',N_\beta\rangle=\mp \langle B_\beta',N_\beta\rangle.$$
I'm stuck finding the isometry, I can also try to find the matrix, but don't know how to connect that with curvature and torsion.

Comment: What do you mean by $\pm -$? Do you mean $\mp$ (written `$\mp$`)?

Comment: I define torsion as $\tau=-\langle B',N\rangle$, but yeah, it would be $\mp$.

Comment: Think about a simple example. Take a right circular helix. What are its curvature and torsion? What helix has the same curvature and opposite torsion?

Comment: $\alpha(s)=(\cos(s/\sqrt{2}),\sin(s/\sqrt{2}),s/\sqrt{2})$ is a circular helix which curvature is $1/2$ and torsion is $1/2$.

Comment: If we take $\beta(s)=-\alpha(s)$, it will have the opposite torsion, right?

Comment: The matrix for the isometry would be $-Id$?

Comment: Yes, can you check? I was thinking of reflecting in the osculating plane at the starting point.